# Given that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^n}$, show that $x f'(x)+n f'(x)=0$.

Tags: derivatives

This exercise was in my math book and of course had no solution as it's a "show" type of question. I don't see how this could hold except for when $x=-n$.

Given that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^n}$, show that $x f'(x)+n f'(x)=0$.

Comment: It's possible the book had a typo, and instead the question was asking you to show that $xf'(x)+nf(x)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the problem.  I am guessing the equation should actually be $$xf'(x)+nf(x)=0$$
so the second $f$ has no derivative.  Assuming this, you just have to substitute.  If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^n}$, then $f'(x)=\frac{-n}{x^{n+1}}$, so
$$xf'(x)+nf(x)$$
$$=\frac{-nx}{x^{n+1}}+\frac{n}{x^{n}} $$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Either $x=-n$ or $n=0$ are the possible solutions.